# Is $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ the same statement as $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} ∃y \in \mathbb{R}$? Etc.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

In general, are the statements "$\exists x,y \in \mathbb{R}$" and "$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$" the exact same as "$\exists x \in \mathbb{R} \exists y \in \mathbb{R}$?" and "$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$," respectively?

If so, why is this the case? If not, how do they differ? For example, if I were to find the negation of "$\forall x,y P(x,y)$," would it be the same as applying the single-variable case $\neg(\forall x P(x)) = \exists x \neg P(x)$? Or is there a different rule? How would it extend to quantifiers of arbitrarily many variables, like $\forall w,x,y,z,\cdots P(w,x,y,z,\cdots)$? Or, maybe, does one statement allow you to let $y$ depend on $x$ while another does not? I'm rather confused on all of these notions and similar ones.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, they are the same. For instance, $\forall x,y\in A$ is an abbreviation for $\forall x \forall y (x\in A \wedge y\in A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\exists x \in A: \phi(x)$ is a standard abbreviation for $\exists x: (x \in A) \land \phi(x)$.

$\forall x,y \in A: \phi(x,y)$ similarly means $\forall x: \forall y (x \in A \land y \in A) \to \phi(x,y)$ etc.

So the existential statements are restricted by an extra "and"-clause asserting membership of the set, universal statements are restricted by adding the membership as a precondition in an implication.

So the negation of $\exists x \in A: \phi(x)$ can be $\forall x: (x \notin A) \lor \lnot \phi(x)$ by applying de Morgan to the conjunction and the usual $\forall$ and $\exists$ swap.

The negation of $\forall x \in A: \phi(x)$ is

$$\lnot\left(\forall x: (x \in A) \to \phi(x)\right) \equiv \exists x: (x \in A) \land \lnot \phi(x) :=: \exists x \in A: \lnot \phi(x) $$

the last by abbreviataion again, so the restricted quantifiers behave the same way among each other (with the same $A$) as unrestricted ones.

Comment: How exactly can the negation of $\exists x \in A : \phi(x)$ be $\forall x : (x \notin A) \lor \neg\phi(x)$? Should it not be $\forall x : (x \in A) \Rightarrow \neg\phi(x)$? edit: Nevermind, I see those two statements are logically equivalent. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JustinT. $\lnot p \lor q$ is equivalent to $p \to q$ so those are equivalent.